# How to convert string to readable date

Tags: java, java.util.date, scriptlet

I have a timestamp value "20150616182115452" which is "yyyyMMddHHmmss ", and i wanted to format it to "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" .

i have tried

```
        String lastLogon = db.getDataAt(0,"VG_QRSE006_L_LGN_TIMESTAMP") ; 
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(lastLogon);
        System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(date));
```

however, i got Unparseable date: "20150616182115452"

Comment: So you parsed a String that looks like `"20150616182115452"` with a formatter, that understands `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"`. What did you expect? Use a correct formatter.

Comment: Use another `SimpleDateFormat` with the correct pattern ( "yyyyMMddHHmmss ") to parse the lastLogon String .

Comment: You say that the format is "yyyyMMddHHmmss" but you're trying to parse it with format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss". It's not surprising that it doesn't work in that case. Use the right format. But even then it wouldn't work because your timestamp value is 3 characters longer than your format string. You're probably missing something in the format.

Comment: Looks to me like you'll need two separate `SimpleDateFormat` objects - one for parsing and one for formatting.  I don't think it will work to just use the same one twice.